# Sitecore and MVC Filters

Tags: asp.net-mvc, sitecore

I want to implement additional global filters in a Sitecore 8 MVC application. It seems like I need to override the default Sitecore InitializeGlobalFilters pipeline. But the lack of documentation makes me nervous. Am I going to break something by overriding this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved by overriding Sitecore's pipeline.

First, created new pipeline:

```
[UsedImplicitly]
public class InitializeGlobalFilters
{
    public virtual void Process(PipelineArgs args)
    {
        this.AddGlobalFilters(args);
    }

    protected virtual void AddGlobalFilters(PipelineArgs args)
    {
        FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        GlobalFilters.Filters.Add(this.CreateRequestFilter());
    }

    protected virtual object CreateRequestFilter()
    {
        return (object)new PipelineBasedRequestFilter();
    }
}
```

Then add patch config that inserted this in the correct location in the pipeline (mimicing where Sitecore had it:

```
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/">
<sitecore>
<pipelines>
  <initialize>
    <processor type="Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.Loader.InitializeGlobalFilters, Sitecore.Mvc">
      <patch:attribute name="type">DD.Platform.Sc.Pipelines.MvcPipelines.InitializeGlobalFilters, DD.Platform.Sc</patch:attribute>
    </processor>        
  </initialize>
</pipelines>
</sitecore>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Quick question, why `FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);`? Is this because we are overriding the `Sitecore.MVC.Pipelines.Loader.InitializeGlobalFilters` where this would have originally occurred? Also, why not patch our InitializeGlobalFilters after the Sitecore version?

Comment: 1. I used FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters) because this is the default structure used in a regular MVC app. Just mimiking the same way of setting up filters. So, set up filters like MVC, just have pipeline call filteradding like it would get called in Global.asax indefault MVC 2. Wanted to replace Sitecores, instead of adding filters twice - mostly about not adding unecessary steps to start up. Startup is slow as it is

Comment: Oh so is this like the FilterConfig.cs file that sits in your App_Start folder? So if I know nothing is in there, then this doesn't necessarily matter? I was wondering if FilterConfig was defined by Sitecore, and had its own logic, but if this is the FitlerConfig in /App_Start, then, at least in our solution, it is doing nothing.

Answer (score 0):

We used  in a one project filters.

In the global.asax we have:

```
 protected void Application_Start()
    {            
        ...
        FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        ...
    }
```

In the App_Start folder we have FilterConfig class

```
public class FilterConfig
{
    public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
    {
        filters.Add(new HandleErrorAttribute());
    }
}
```

We have also a filter class

```
public class AllowCrossSiteJsonAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{

    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        .... 
        base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
    }
}
```

and everything works fine, we didn't ovveride InitializeGlobalFilters pipeline.

Comment: Im really trying to avoid editing the Global.asax file if at all possible.

Comment: I just did the route table in Sitecore for the same reason, to not override the Global.ascx. Please read my blog and see if this can lead you in the right direction. This is Route Table, but  I think the overrides will be similar. http://www.waitingimpatiently.com/moving-controllers-in-to-sitecore/

Answer (score 0):

For the record, I went back to the `Sitecore.Mvc.dll` and decompiled it so I could see what the previously registered `Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.Loader.InitialzeGlobalFilters.cs` class was doing. Here it is. I am going to go ahead in my implementation, and configure both of them, rather safe than sorry. I also decompiled the `PipelineBasedRequestFilter.cs` which also looked like logic i'd rather leave in place.

```
// Decompiled with JetBrains decompiler
// Type: Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.Loader.InitializeGlobalFilters
// Assembly: Sitecore.Mvc, Version=1.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null
// MVID: 4DE79547-0FD4-45A0-BD18-FFEF21AA18FC
// Assembly location: C:\P2\packages\Sitecore.Mvc.NoReferences.8.2.180406\lib\NET452\Sitecore.Mvc.dll

using Sitecore.Mvc.Filters;
using Sitecore.Pipelines;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.Loader
{
  [UsedImplicitly]
  public class InitializeGlobalFilters
  {
    public virtual void Process(PipelineArgs args)
    {
      this.AddGlobalFilters(args);
    }

    protected virtual void AddGlobalFilters(PipelineArgs args)
    {
      GlobalFilters.Filters.Add(this.CreateRequestFilter());
    }

    protected virtual object CreateRequestFilter()
    {
      return (object) new PipelineBasedRequestFilter();
    }
  }
}
```

PipelineBasedRequestFilter.cs

```
// Decompiled with JetBrains decompiler
// Type: Sitecore.Mvc.Filters.PipelineBasedRequestFilter
// Assembly: Sitecore.Mvc, Version=1.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null
// MVID: 4DE79547-0FD4-45A0-BD18-FFEF21AA18FC
// Assembly location: C:\P2\packages\Sitecore.Mvc.NoReferences.8.2.180406\lib\NET452\Sitecore.Mvc.dll

using Sitecore.Diagnostics;
using Sitecore.Mvc.Diagnostics;
using Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines;
using Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.MvcEvents.ActionExecuted;
using Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.MvcEvents.ActionExecuting;
using Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.MvcEvents.Exception;
using Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.MvcEvents.ResultExecuted;
using Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.MvcEvents.ResultExecuting;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace Sitecore.Mvc.Filters
{
  public class PipelineBasedRequestFilter : IActionFilter, IResultFilter, IExceptionFilter
  {
    public virtual void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext actionExecutedContext)
    {
      Assert.ArgumentNotNull((object) actionExecutedContext, nameof (actionExecutedContext));
      using (TraceBlock.Start("Action Executed"))
        PipelineService.Get().RunPipeline<ActionExecutedArgs>("mvc.actionExecuted", new ActionExecutedArgs(actionExecutedContext));
    }

    public virtual void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext actionExecutingContext)
    {
      Assert.ArgumentNotNull((object) actionExecutingContext, nameof (actionExecutingContext));
      using (TraceBlock.Start("Action Executing"))
        PipelineService.Get().RunPipeline<ActionExecutingArgs>("mvc.actionExecuting", new ActionExecutingArgs(actionExecutingContext));
    }

    public virtual void OnException(ExceptionContext exceptionContext)
    {
      Assert.ArgumentNotNull((object) exceptionContext, nameof (exceptionContext));
      using (TraceBlock.Start("Exception event"))
        PipelineService.Get().RunPipeline<ExceptionArgs>("mvc.exception", new ExceptionArgs(exceptionContext));
    }

    public virtual void OnResultExecuted(ResultExecutedContext resultExecutedContext)
    {
      Assert.ArgumentNotNull((object) resultExecutedContext, nameof (resultExecutedContext));
      using (TraceBlock.Start("Result Executed event"))
        PipelineService.Get().RunPipeline<ResultExecutedArgs>("mvc.resultExecuted", new ResultExecutedArgs(resultExecutedContext));
    }

    public virtual void OnResultExecuting(ResultExecutingContext resultExecutingContext)
    {
      Assert.ArgumentNotNull((object) resultExecutingContext, nameof (resultExecutingContext));
      using (TraceBlock.Start("Result Executing event"))
        PipelineService.Get().RunPipeline<ResultExecutingArgs>("mvc.resultExecuting", new ResultExecutingArgs(resultExecutingContext));
    }
  }
}
```

Edit:

Oh and one more thing, coincidentally I figured out what the `PipelineBasedRequestFilter.cs` is used for! Turns out it looks like it's being used for some of the profiling in the Sitecore Debugger! 
http://www.glass.lu/Blog/Archive/Using%20the%20Sitecore%20Debug%20Tool%20Part%201

[image]